# Deserializing xml with duplicate entries using xstream

Tags: java, xstream

I am trying to read in an xml file and store its contents as an object for later use.  I can reproduce a similar object using the toXML() method and providing sample data however when I call fromXML() on the same object I get an error.  The problem is I have multiple instances of fiels.  The xml looks something like this...

```
<House>   
  <Address>
    <Number>1234</Number>
    <Street>Sample St.</Street>
    <City>Sample City</City>
  </Address>
  <Resident>
    <Name>Joe</Name>
    <Age>38</Age>
    <Profession>
      <Title>Engineer</Title>
      <Title>Developer</Title>
    </Profession>
  </Resident>
  <Resident>
    <Name>Cathy</Name>
    <Age>35</Age>
    <Profession>
      <Title>Engineer</Title>
      <Title>Developer</Title>
    </Profession>
  </Resident>
</House>
```

So in this example there are two residents and they each have two job titles.  I tried defining these tags as arraylists in the constructors' for their respective classes but that didn't seem to work.  This works fine if I only have one instance of  Resident or Title etc.

Here is the Java code (copied from comment below):

```
XStream xstream = new XStream(new DomDriver()); 
FileReader fin = new FileReader("path_to_file.xml"); 
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fin); 

while(br.ready())
{ 
  str += br.readLine() + "\n"; 
} 

House house = (House)xstream.fromXML(str);


import java.util.ArrayList;


public class House {

private Address Address;
private ArrayList<Resident> Resident;

public House(Address address, ArrayList<Resident> resident) {

    Address = address;
    Resident = resident;
}

public Address getAddress() {
    return Address;
}

public void setAddress(Address address) {
    Address = address;
}

public ArrayList<Resident> getResident() {
    return Resident;
}

public void setResident(ArrayList<Resident> resident) {
    Resident = resident;
}

}
```

Comment: Can you please show your Java code which is calling fromXML()? Also, please explain "that didn't seem to work" and show the error you've received.

Comment: XStream xstream = new XStream(new DomDriver());
    FileReader fin = new FileReader("path_to_file.xml");
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fin);
    while(br.ready()){
      str += br.readLine() + "\n";
    }
    House house = (House)xstream.fromXML(str);

Exception in thread "main" com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.reflection.AbstractReflectionConverter$DuplicateFieldException: House
---- Debugging information ----
duplicate-field     : Resident
class               : House
path                : /House/Resident[2]

Comment: I should specify: the information I requested, you should put in the question. Easier for all to read. Also, please show the source of House.java.

Comment: Would be helpful if you included your class definition of `House`. Also, you can modify your original question to include the requested updates. Putting it in comments makes it harder to understand your problem and help you.

Answer (score 3):

Here is how to do it using annotations.

```
@XStreamAlias("house")
public class House{

@XStreamAlias("Address")
private String address;

@XStreamImplicit
protected List<Resident> residents;

    ...
```

}

And at the Resident class you do:

```
@XStreamAlias("resident")
public class Resident{

@XStreamAlias("name")
private String name;

@XStreamAlias("age")
private int age;

@XStreamAlias("profession")
private String profession;


@XStreamImplicit
protected List<String> titles

    ...
```

}

Remember to process the annotations.