# Repeating element deserialize using XStream

Tags: java, xml, deserialization, xstream

I am using XStream 1.4.3 to move between Java and XML documents when messaging to another process. Most everything works.  However, I can't seem to get one reply document to deserialize properly. Here is the reply:

```
<AddToBatchResponse>
    <MerchantOrderNumber>1525675</MerchantOrderNumber>
    <MerchantOrderNumber>1525676</MerchantOrderNumber>
    <ResponseReasonCode>100</ResponseReasonCode>
    <AuthResponseType>S</AuthResponseType>
</AddToBatchResponse>
```

When XStream gets to the 2nd MerchantOrderNumber, it gives an error saying "Duplicate field MerchantOrderNumber".  I've tried different designs, but it just won't work.  Here is the relevant Java code:

Snippet from calling class

```
xstream.alias("AddToBatchResponse", AddToBatchResponse.class);
xstream.alias("MerchantOrderNumber", OrderNumber.class);
xstream.addImplicitCollection(AddToBatchResponse.class, "orderNumbers");
response = (AddToBatchResponse)xstream.fromXML(responseXml);
```

AddToBatchResponse.java (leaving out getters and setters)

```
public class AddToBatchResponse {
protected List<OrderNumber> orderNumbers;
protected String ResponseReasonCode; 
protected String AuthResponseType;  
    ...
```

OrderNumber.java

```
public class OrderNumber {
protected String MerchantOrderNumber;
...
```

Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong?  Thanks.

Comment: Should mention - I want to do this without using annotations.

Comment: what parser are you using with XStream? With the default XPP3 I wasn't able to reproduce your error.

Comment: StAX parser - do you think that's an issue?

Comment: I can only presume that the StAX parser is stricter in its handling of the XML. How are you actually instantiating your xstream instance?

Comment: xstream = new XStream(new StaxDriver());

Comment: I am currently unable to reproduce your error. Using the following code works fine for me: `XStream xstream = new XStream(new StaxDriver());
xstream.alias("AddToBatchResponse", AddToBatchResponse.class);
xstream.alias("MerchantOrderNumber", OrderNumber.class);
xstream.addImplicitCollection(AddToBatchResponse.class, "orderNumbers");` The MerchantOrderNumber values within the 2 OrderNumbers that are created are null. However that is easily fixed by registering a custom SingleValueConverter for the OrderNumber class. I'm using xstream 1.4.3 and stax 1.2.0. Sorry I can't offer any further help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, no answer - so here's what I did:

I used regex + String manipulation to pull out and process the extra elements in my code.  Not elegant not desirable, but it works.  If anyone ever finds an answer to this question, please share.

Comment: Mark, I found this other question that can help you too. It uses @XStreamImplicit http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7491195/deserializing-xml-with-duplicate-entries-using-xstream